# Get RSA keys in Crypto-Js

Tags: reactjs, cryptojs

I want to generate the public key using Crypto Js , I googled it every where ,but can't able to find the answer. In the documents of crypto-js,there also not properly mentioned , how to get the public using RSA in crypto-js .

I am from the java background , There we easily generate the private and public key

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        Map<String, Object> keys = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        String secretPublicKey = "fdfdfdfd";// just dummy
        KeyFactory keyFactory =null;
        keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(android.util.Base64.decode(secretPublicKey, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT));
        keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
        Log.e("publicKey----->>",""+publicKey);
```

But it hard time to find the public key in crypto-js . Hoping any one can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you're referring to the crypto module in Node.js. There is a function that should be able to do what you want to do: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_generatekeypairsync_type_options

Here's a snippet of code lifted from the docs:

```js
const { generateKeyPairSync } = require('crypto');
const { publicKey, privateKey } = generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
  modulusLength: 4096,
  publicKeyEncoding: {
    type: 'spki',
    format: 'pem'
  },
  privateKeyEncoding: {
    type: 'pkcs8',
    format: 'pem',
    cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',
    passphrase: 'top secret'
  }
});
```

Comment: crypto and crypto-js is two different library. I am using crypto-js